# Is there a way to use Python to read and process a camera's frame then save it to a file. Without using libraries such as OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

This is what I have at the moment but its getting really slow read times. It takes about 6-8 seconds alone just to read the frame with opencv and for my project I need to be able to get a picture at specific intervals as it reads a pressure transducer. Is there a way to make this program faster with cv2 or can is there a way using arrays or what not to do this much quicker.

````
import cv2
import timeit
def main(): #Define camera function
    start = timeit.default_timer() #Starts a runtime timer
    hud_Cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Call camera resource
    gauge_Cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    rval, hud_Img = hud_Cam.read() #Read/Grab camera frame
    rval, gauge_Img = gauge_Cam.read()
    stop = timeit.default_timer() #Stops a runtime timer
    print('Time: ', stop - start) #Calculate runtime timer
    start1 = timeit.default_timer() #Starts a runtime timer
    hud_name = ('HudPicture0.jpg') #Initialize file names
    gauge_name = ('GaugePicture0.jpg')
    cv2.imwrite(hud_name, hud_Img) #Write camera frame to file names
    cv2.imwrite(gauge_name, gauge_Img)
    print("Hud Picture written!") #Log to console
    print("Gauge Picture written!")
    hud_Cam.release() #Release camera resource to clear memory
    gauge_Cam.release()
    stop1 = timeit.default_timer() #Stops a runtime timer
    print('Time: ', stop1 - start1) #Calculate runtime timer```
````

Comment: The answer is yes, by rewriting everything from opencv in Python. Most likely this will not be quicker than using existing libraries that have already been optimized.

Comment: Unless your camera resolution is huge, it probably shouldn't be taking that long. For instance I can decode 4k frames at over 5 fps with OpenCV.

Comment: Can I have some helps figuring out ways to optimize this code? It's taking way to long for my application.

Comment: But what if I don't need everything from opencv what if I just need these modules I used and not the full library

Comment: Your timing isn't very representative as your code isn't how this type of thing normally works. You normally set up video capture **outside** the main loop and **outside** any timing. You then normally acquire repeatedly inside a loop and you don't normally save every frame to disk - since you normally process them. Also you can use multiple threads and/or processes...

Comment: Can I have an example please

Comment: Sure... https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html

Comment: My problem is I don't want to have to break the loop with waitKey and I don't even need it to loop because I only need it to take a picture with two cameras then write it to file then stop. The program will only run when told to by labview so It doesn't need to loop.

Comment: I only need it to do what I tell it to do one time

Comment: Ok. What are the cameras (make/model), how are they attached and what is your operating system, please?

Comment: Windows 10,  depstech/uhd endoscope 5m/16.5ft, both are USB

Comment: If you just want a single frame, why are you using video? Doesn't the manufacturer supply software to take a single shot that you could use?

Comment: I'm not using it for the manufacturers use. I'm using it to take a picture of a gauge when a pressure transducer reads a certain pressure. I just need to take a picture not a video. My code shouldn't be taking video it's just a live feed until a picture is taken. After the picture is taken it needs to be written to a .jpg where labview grabs it and manipulates it.

Comment: Initialize the videoCapture outside the main() function and write a while(True) loop and break the loop once you capture and save one image.

Comment: @prabhakar-sivanesan i moved gauge_Cam and hud_Cam above main and used while loop to loop main one time and that brought the time down to Time:  6.530238300000008ish

Comment: anyway to get it down further from 6.5

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want to be able to take two images from two cameras as soon as possible after Labview requests it.

On Linux or macOS, I would start capturing continuously as soon as possible and then signal the capturing process using Unix signals. Unfortunately, you are using Windows and signals don't work so well there. So, I am going to use the filesystem to signal - if Labview wants a picture taken, it just creates a file with or without content called `capture.txt` and that makes the Python process save the current image. There are other more sophisticated methods, but this demonstrates the concept and as you learn more, you may replace the signalling mechanism with a write on a socket, or an MQTT message or something else.

I put the two cameras in two independent threads so they can work in parallel, i.e. faster.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import threading
import logging
from pathlib import Path

def capture(stream, path):
   """Capture given stream and save to file on demand"""

   # Start capturing to RAM
   logging.info(f'[captureThread]: starting stream {stream}')
   cam = cv2.VideoCapture(stream, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

   while True:

      # Read video continuously
      _, im = cam.read()

      # Check if Labview wants it
      if CaptureFile.exists():
         # Intermediate filename
         temp = Path(f'saving-{stream}.jpg')

         # Save image with temporary name
         cv2.imwrite(str(temp), im)

         # Rename so Labview knows it is complete and not still being written
         temp.rename(path)

         logging.info(f'[captureThread]: image saved')
         break

   logging.info(f'[captureThread]: done')


if __name__=="__main__":
   # Set up logging - advisable when threading
   format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
   logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
   logging.info("[MAIN]: starting")

   # Labview will create this file when a capture is required, ensure not there already
   CaptureFile = Path('capture.txt')
   CaptureFile.unlink(True)

   # Create a thread for each camera and start them
   HUDthread   = threading.Thread(target=capture, args=(0, Path('HUD.jpg')))
   Gaugethread = threading.Thread(target=capture, args=(1, Path('Gauge.jpg')))
   HUDthread.start()
   Gaugethread.start()

   # Wait for both to exit
   HUDthread.join()
   Gaugethread.join()

   logging.info("[MAIN]: done")
```

Comment: Yeah I don't have the knowledge yet to understand what your program is doing but I'm gonna test it and give it a try on my computer. Thanks for the information. If I have any questions I'll let you know.

Comment: Could you show me how you're implementing this into labview?

Comment: Also what exactly is the parameter stream correlate with to labview. I know path is a path block you connect to the input of the python node but what is stream and where do I connect it to the python node

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I am suggesting you run this code totally independently of Labview. Whenever Labview wants images to be saved it just creates a file called `"capture.txt"` and 30ms later the two images are saved. That's all.

Comment: I got a way that I used threading to run each frame in parallel. I still have figured out what logging is, but I will. Next I'm gonna find a way to skip writing the camera Frame to drive and just get the rgb values from the frame and grab those with Labview.

Comment: No need to get hung up on logging - it just writes messages on the screen for debugging. Just run the program, and then create a file called `"capture.txt"` and you will immediately see the program saves two images and stops. When that works, create the file using Labview and it will do exactly the same. You can create the file with `DIR > capture.txt` - it doesn't matter what's in it.

Comment: Do you know how to get the rgb values from a cv2 camera frame so I can avoid saving to disk and I can just send the data straight to labview

Comment: The values are already there in my code in the variable `im`. If your question is about sending that to Labview, it is very different from your original question so just ask a new question to make sure the right people answer.

Answer (score 0):

This got the time down to, Time:2.066412200000059

````
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
import cv2
hud_Cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #Call camera resource
gauge_Cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

def main(hud_Cam, gauge_Cam, start): #Define camera function
    while True:
        rval, hud_Img = hud_Cam.read() #Read/Grab camera frame
        rval, gauge_Img = gauge_Cam.read()
        hud_name = ('HudPicture0.jpg') #Initialize file names
        gauge_name = ('GaugePicture0.jpg')
        cv2.imwrite(hud_name, hud_Img) #Write camera frame to file names
        cv2.imwrite(gauge_name, gauge_Img)
        print("Hud Picture written!") #Log to console
        print("Gauge Picture written!")
        hud_Cam.release() #Release camera resource to clear memory
        gauge_Cam.release()
        stop = timeit.default_timer()
        print('Time: ', stop - start) #Calculate runtime timer
        break
# =============================================================================
    while True:
        img1 = cv2.imread(hud_name)
        img2 = cv2.imread(gauge_name)
        cv2.imshow("Hud Image", img1)
        cv2.imshow("Gauge Image", img2)
        k = cv2.waitKey(60)
        if k%256 == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

main(hud_Cam, gauge_Cam, start) #Call camera function```
````