# How do I grab the RGB values of two cameras using Python cv2 and send it to LabVIEW without writing anything to disk?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, python-3.6, labview

I'm trying to change this code to grab the actual RGB values of a camera frame instead of writing an image as a .jpg. I need to be able to send these RGB values into LabVIEW to be viewed and manipulated. Any advice would be great. I used threading to make both pictures be taken at the same time instead of sequentially to speed up the program.

```
from threading import Thread #Library for assigning code to different cpu threads to run in parallel rather than sequentially
import os #Library for editing system files directly
import cv2 #Library for image & video processing

def _HudCam_(): #Define Hud Camera Function

        #Call Hud camera resource
        hud_Cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) 

        #If Hud camera is not found
        if not hud_Cam.isOpened():
                #Log error to console
                raise RuntimeError('Error opening Hud Camera.')
        
        #Set resolution of camera to 720p
        hud_Cam.set(3, 1280)
        hud_Cam.set(4, 720)

        #Read/Grab Hud camera frame
        rval, hud_Img = hud_Cam.read()

        #Initialize file name
        hud_name = ('C:/Users/Betty/Downloads/HudPicture-0.jpg') 

        #Write Hud camera frame to file name
        cv2.imwrite(hud_name, hud_Img) 

        #Initialize rename hud jpg variable
        old_file1 = os.path.join("C:/Users/Betty/Downloads", "HudPicture-0.jpg") 

        #Initialize rename hud jpg variable
        new_file1 = os.path.join("C:/Users/Betty/Downloads", "HudPicture0.jpg") 

        #If a file exists under the renamed files path
        if (os.path.exists('C:/Users/Betty/Downloads/HudPicture0.jpg')):

                #Delete the file in the path
                os.remove('C:/Users/Betty/Downloads/HudPicture0.jpg')

        #Rename file so labview knows its not being written to
        os.rename(old_file1, new_file1) 

        #Log to console
        print("Hud Picture written!") 

        #Release camera resource to clear memory
        hud_Cam.release() 

def _GaugeCam_(): #Define Gauge Camera Function

        #Call Gauge camera resource
        gauge_Cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) 

        #If gauge camera is not found
        if not gauge_Cam.isOpened():
                #Log error to console
                raise RuntimeError('Error opening Gauge Camera.')
        
        #Set resolution of camera to 720p
        gauge_Cam.set(3, 1280) 
        gauge_Cam.set(4, 720)

        #Read/Grab Gauge camera frame
        rval, gauge_Img = gauge_Cam.read() 

        #Initialize file name
        gauge_name = ('C:/Users/Betty/Downloads/GaugePicture-0.jpg') 

        #Write Gauge camera frame to file name
        cv2.imwrite(gauge_name, gauge_Img) 

        #Initialize rename gauge .jpg variable
        old_file2 = os.path.join("C:/Users/Betty/Downloads", "GaugePicture-0.jpg") 

        #Initialize rename gauge .jpg variable
        new_file2 = os.path.join("C:/Users/Betty/Downloads", "GaugePicture0.jpg") 

        #If a file exists under the renamed files path
        if (os.path.exists('C:/Users/Betty/Downloads/GaugePicture0.jpg')): 

                #Delete the file in the path
                os.remove('C:/Users/Betty/Downloads/GaugePicture0.jpg')

        #Rename file so labview knows its not being written to
        os.rename(old_file2, new_file2) 

        #Log to console
        print("Gauge Picture written!") 

        #Release camera resource to clear memory
        gauge_Cam.release() 

def main():

        #Assigns hud camera function to its own cpu thread
        t1= Thread(target = _HudCam_)
        #Assigns guage camera function to its own cpu thread
        t2= Thread(target = _GaugeCam_)
        #Starts hud function in its own cpu thread
        t1.start() 
        #Starts gauge function in its own cpu thread
        t2.start()
        #Rejoin threads to run sequentially
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
```

Comment: Implement TCP/IP communication between Python and LabVIEW applications. Then, Python will send image as bytes stream to LabVIEW via TCP/IP, without writing to disk.

Comment: Tcp/ip? Communication?

Comment: For anyone answering/commenting, this refers... https://stackoverflow.com/a/67381576/2836621

Comment: I do not use LabView but it seems it is capable of TCP/IP communication (i.e. socket communication) so if you can work out how to receive your image in LabView, we can probably work out how to send it from Python. See https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvconcepts/using_labview_with_tcp_ip_and_udp/ You will almost certainly want TCP and not UDP - which is unreliable.

Comment: If you are not that happy with programming, you may find you get on better with a RAMdrive, which is a lump of your PC's RAM that is made to look like a disk. You could write your JPEG images there from Python (without going to real *spinning* disk) and read them from LabView. I don't use Windows but some likely candidates are probably "Dataram RAMDisk", "AMD Radeon RAMDisk", "ImDisk", "Gavotte RAMDisk"

Comment: TestScript is a fully bidirectional LabVIEW/Python communicator that has all that TCP/IP stuff done for you. You can call a LabVIEW function you define, with arguments like large datasets, quite easily. Check it out. It's free and source-released, mostly written by yours truly when I was working for Wineman.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I assume you are referring to this? http://www.genuen.com/blog/testscript-python-labview-connector ... to which you are related?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yep: Genuen is the new name of CertTech, which acquired Wineman a couple of years ago.

Comment: Cool, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Have you considered the option of acquiring the images directly from the camera into LabVIEW? It looks to me as if your cameras use DirectShow in which case I think you need NI-IMAQdx which is part of NI's [Vision Acquisition Software](https://www.ni.com/en-gb/shop/software/products/vision-acquisition-software.html). If your licence doesn't include that already then there may be third-party options.

Comment: You can also give the [python_labview_automation](https://github.com/ni/python_labview_automation) package a try. It can run a VI from python.

Comment: You can use OpenCV with the EmguCV wrapper in LabVIEW to implement this code.